# Is there away to handle broken links in Highslide?

Tags: highslide

We currently use a highslide gallery at our site (www.teesaw.com).  The gallery is comprised of a number of images that are hosted at a number of external sources.  At times, our PHP script will pull in a reference to an image that doesn't exist (or is blocked by a user's web filters) which results in a broken link.

When using the slider to move between images, it will get stuck on the 'LOADING' part when the next image is a broken link.  Is there any way to have highslide detect this and automatically skip it?

Please help! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be taken care of by modifying the code of highslide-full.js itself, and putting in a routine that calls some default image on your site (like an "oops!" image of some sort) if the loader times out. See the old Highslide forum:

http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=16664&p=69519

Comment: I've uploaded a live demo: http://roadrash.no/hs-support/handle-missing-images.html

Answer (score 1):

There is also this solution, seems simple enough:

http://roadrash.no/hs-support/handle-missing-images.html

> You just put this code after line 1266 in highslide-with-gallery.js
>   (or right after line 1473 in highslide-full.js):

```
img.onerror = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        img.src = hs.graphicsDir + 'no-image.png';
        if (hs.ie) { // FIX FOR IE9
            img.width = img.naturalWidth;
            img.height = img.naturalHeight;
        }
    }, 1000);
};
```